# Firebase 3 - ref.getAuth() equivalent

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In Firebase 2 I was able to do a synchronous check to see if the user was logged in, e.g:

```
if (!ref.getAuth()) ..go to login page
else ..show page
```

I can access the `currentUser` state with `firebase.auth().currentUser` so I tried to do:

```
if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) ..go to login page
else ..show page
```

The problem is that this is always initially null, so it redirects to the login page, then a few moments later `onAuthStateChanged` happens and the user is logged in.

Is there still a way to synchronously check this? Or otherwise is there a promise I can listen to so that I can show a loading spinner or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using an auth state listener to determine if the user is signed in.

```js
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    console.log('authStateChanged', user);
    if (user) {
      console.log("Welcome UID:" + user.uid);
    }
  });
```

When you attach that listener right away, it will fire with the correct state.

When I run the app, sign in and reload the page, the log outputs:

> authStateChanged Fl {...}
>
> Welcome UID:052289713245805425655890E9024AB4ADBA5404B3C0

So you can use the first time the listener is called to detect if the user is already signed in.

Comment: Thanks but for me there is a small 2s or so delay, I think I'll have to show a loading spinner and then redirect or show the page when `onAuthStateChanged` happens.

Comment: With the above code the flow is correct. If the delay is noticeable to the user, you can easily add a loading indicator by showing it when the view loads and hiding it when `onAuthStateChanged()` fires.

Comment: That's what I've done - good to know I wasn't missing something and it's the expected way

Comment: @DominicTobias  i'm using firebase w/ a react+redux app and I am using firebase.auth().currentUser to successfully login in user, save it to local state and redirect user to authorized page using react-router. I also attached onAuthStateChanged to componentWillMount function on my main App container. This does allow me to get the auth user info on reload (i confirmed using redux chrome extension). Yet the react-router redirect never occurs. any thoughts or suggestion. If you have sample code, that would be great .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and because I'm using Angular, I found a synchronous call $getAuth() in AngularFire. https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#getauth

Maybe there's an equivalent in ReactFire library as well. :)